# Given two trees, return true if they are structurally identical they are made of nodes with the same values arranged in the same way

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static boolean identical(treenode<Integer> root1,treenode<Integer> root2)
    {
        boolean ans;
        for(int i=0;i<root1.children.size();i++)
        for(int j=0;j<root2.children.size();j++)
        {
         boolean subans=identical(root1.children.get(i),root2.children.get(j));
         ans=subans;
        }
        if(root1.data==root2.data)
        {
            ans=true;
        }/* what's wrong with the code*/
        else{
            ans=false;
        }
        return ans;
    }/* how can i improve it ? */
```

i am not able to understand why my code is not working.please tell me the solutions to fix it.

Comment: It seems that you are doing this test only for two given nodes. You have to test the entire tree, so you have to call this function recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is going through every recursive call of `identical` before evaluating the boolean return of those recursive calls. In other words, you're not evaluating the data of all of the children through your recursive calls. I believe with your code that you may only be evaluating the last child node of every node in the tree (going down the right-most side).

You also have a nested for loop, which is unnecessary in your case.

What I propose is this:

1) Check that the values of your current nodes are the same. If not, or if at least one is null, return false immediately.

2) Check that the sizes of the children are the same for both nodes. If not, return false.

3) Call this recursively with each child node.

This is a depth first, left-side-first search.

Comment: where are the brackets for the outer for loop?

Comment: @JakeMcGlone a for loop with one line inside it doesn't need opening/closing brackets. In this case, the outer loop's single content is the inner for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean structurallyIdentical(Node tnode, Node onode) {
    if(tnode == null && onode == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if(tnode != null && onode != null) {
        // check that the left branch is identical
        boolean left = structurallyIdentical(tnode.left, onode.left);
        // check that the right branch is identical
        boolean right = structurallyIdentical(tnode.right, onode.right);
        // only identical, if both branches match
        return (left && right);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solves it for a binary tree (2 children), the original question was for a generic tree (any number of children).

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement based on @Vansh Nandwani's answer.
SBT = Same Binary Tree

```
    public  boolean SBT(BinNode root1, BinNode root2)
    {
        if (root1 == null && root2 == null) return true;
        if (root1 != null && root1 != null) {
            if (root1.value() == root2.value())//check if the values are the same 
               {
                boolean left = SBT(root1.left(), root2.left());
                boolean right = SBT(root1.right(), root2.right);
                return (left && right);}
                } 
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

/*  TreeNode structure 
    class TreeNode<T> {
        T data;
        ArrayList<TreeNode<T>> children;

        TreeNode(T data){
            this.data = data;
            children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>();
        }
    }*/
    
    public static boolean checkIdentical(TreeNode<Integer> root1, TreeNode<Integer> root2){

        if(root1.children.size()!=root2.children.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
         if(root1.children.size()==root2.children.size()){
            if(root1.data==root2.data)
            {
                for(int i=0 ,j=0;i<root1.children.size()&&j<root2.children.size();i++ ,j++){
                    checkIdentical(root1.children.get(i),root2.children.get(j));
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and please fix the codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool areIdentical(TreeNode<int> *root1, TreeNode<int> * root2) 
    {bool ans=false;
    
    
        if(root1->children.size()!=root2->children.size())
        {
            ans =false;
        }
         if(root1->children.size()==root2->children.size()){
            if(root1->data==root2->data)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<root1->children.size();j++){
                    areIdentical(root1->children[j],root2->children[j]);
                    ans=true;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answering! it would help improve the answer if you could provide an explanation of how it answers the original post. thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For general tree

Method 1:

```
bool areIdentical(TreeNode<int> *root1, TreeNode<int> * root2) {
    
    
    if(root1 == NULL && root2 == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    if((root1 == NULL && root2 != NULL) || (root1 != NULL && root2 == NULL)){
        return false;
    }
    if((root1->data != root2->data)|| (root1->children.size() != root2->children.size())){
         return false;
    }
    else if(root1->children.size() == root2->children.size()){
        if(root1->data == root2->data){
           for(int i=0,j=0;i<root1->children.size()&&j<root2->children.size();i++,j++){
                    areIdentical(root1->children[i],root2->children[j]);
                    return true;
           }
        }
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

//this solution may fail some testcase but
Method 2 : work perfectly fine

Method 2 :

```
bool areIdentical(TreeNode<int> *root1, TreeNode<int> * root2) {
    if(root1 == NULL && root2 == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    if((root1 == NULL && root2 != NULL) || (root1 != NULL && root2 == NULL)){
        return false;
    }
    if((root1->data != root2->data)|| (root1->children.size() != root2->children.size())){
         return false;
    }
    for(int  i = 0;i < root1->children.size();++i){
        TreeNode<int>* child1 = root1->children[i];
        TreeNode<int>* child2 = root2->children[i];
        if(!areIdentical(child1,child2)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Structurally identical

```
public static boolean checkIdentical(TreeNode<Integer> root1, TreeNode<Integer> root2){

    int size1=root1.children.size();
    int size2=root2.children.size();
    if(root1==null && root2==null){
        return true;
    }
    if((root1==null && root2!=null) || (root1!=null && root2==null)){
        return false;
    }
    if((root1.data!=root2.data)||(size1!=size2)){
        return false;
    }
    
    if(size1==size2){
        if(root1.data==root2.data){
            for(int i =0;i<size1;i++){
             for(int j=0;j<size2;j++){
                 TreeNode<Integer> child1=root1.children.get(i);
                 TreeNode<Integer> child2=root2.children.get(i);
                 if(!checkIdentical(child1,child2)){
                     return false;
                 }
             }   
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
    
}
```